# MonoCecil giving the wrong method name when reading an F# binary by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, f#, mono

I have a net 6 F# binary that contains some methods, on which some have one or many `[<TestCategory(CategoryName)>]` attribute defined on them. My goal is to use reflection, from a C# application, to read and gather the fully qualified names of those test methods.

In order to achieve this, I am trying to use the Mono.Cecil library in order to read the information from the F# binary. This seems to work pretty well with C# binaries, but not so much with F# ones. The problem I am encountering is that the fully qualified name (and name) properties of the method Mono.Cecil gives me is under the format "*BinaryName*.*ModuleName*.f@*LineNumber*", instead of giving me "*BinaryName*.*ModuleName*.*ActualMethodName*".

Here is how I get the information via reflection using Mono.Cecil.

```
    private static IEnumerable<GenericModule> ReadModulesRecursively(string assemblyPath)
    {
        var modules = new List<GenericModule>();

        var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);
        foreach (var module in assemblyDefinition.Modules)
        {
            var moduleTypes = module.Types.Select(ToGenericType); // Construct a DTO containing only what I want
            modules.Add(new GenericModule(module.Name, moduleTypes));
        }

        return modules;
    }

    private static GenericType ToGenericType(TypeDefinition typeDefinition)
    {
        return new GenericType(typeDefinition.Name, typeDefinition.CustomAttributes.Select(ToGenericAttribute), typeDefinition.Methods.Select(ToGenericMethod));
    }

    private static GenericMethod ToGenericMethod(MethodDefinition methodDefinition)
    {
        return new GenericMethod(methodDefinition.Name, $"{methodDefinition.DeclaringType.FullName}.{methodDefinition.Name}", methodDefinition.DeclaringType.FullName,
            methodDefinition.CustomAttributes.Select(ToGenericAttribute));
    }
```

And here is an example of a F# method declaration I am trying to get information on, in the F# binary:

```
module myModule

<open statements...>

[<TestClass>]
[<DeploymentItem("Deploy1")>]
[<DeploymentItem("Deploy2")>]
type Tests ()=

    [<TestMethod>]
    [<TestCategory("Cat1")>]
    [<TestCategory("Cat2")>]
    member x.``This is a test title`` () =
        ()
```

So the problem here seems to be that the MonoCecil `MethodDefinition` type doesn't contain the right Name and FullName property values.

Is this a known issue with MonoCecil and F#, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you have a way to reliably reproduce this, talk to the author(s) please, https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us enough of your code to reproduce what you're seeing, but this short test seems to work correctly (or at least differently from what you're describing):

```cs
var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);
var myModule = assemblyDefinition.MainModule.Types
    .Where(type => type.Name == "myModule")
    .Single();
var testsType = myModule.NestedTypes.Single();
var testMethod = testsType.Methods
    .Where(method => method.Name == "This is a test title")
    .Single();
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {testMethod.Name}");   // "This is a test title"
Console.WriteLine($"Full name: {testMethod.FullName}");   // "System.Void myModule/Tests::This is a test title()"
```

Note that the method's `Name` property is `"This is a test title"`, as expected. The `FullName` also looks correct, although I can't say for certain.

Neither of the outputs follow the pattern you describe, so I suspect the problem is actually in your code. However, without seeing more of your program, it's hard to say for sure.

It's important to understand that the F# compiler's idea of a module doesn't necessarily correspond to what you might expect. In particular, the F# `myModule` module gets compiled into a type that then contains a nested `Tests` type.